# How to set screen orientation according to a video's height and width

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-videoview

I am using `videoview`, in the `onPrepared` method and it returns the media player height and width. Then I check if the width of the video is greater than the height and rotate the screen. The problem is that if I rotate the screen orientation, it again calls the `onCreate` method and then recalls all of the code so it takes time to initialize the video again.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.play_video_activity);

        // Insert your Video URL
        String VideoURL = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";

        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

        // Create a progressbar
        final ProgressDialog pDialog;
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayVideoActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    PlayVideoActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();

                if(mp.getVideoWidth()> mp.getVideoHeight())
                {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: if(videoview.getVideoWidth()> videoview.getVideoHeight())  check this condition

Comment: This condition works properly . See OnPrepared method.

Comment: your checking mediaplayer's hieght and width... do same thing  for videoview

Comment: but the quesion is that suppose the video width is 480 and height is 640, then I will show video in portrait mode(which is by default), but if width is 640 and height is 480 then i have to show video in landscape mode but in this case if I rotate video in landscape mode it again initialize video because the activity again call onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity in manifest file

Declare variables in your activity

```
boolean orienChanged = false;
int lastOrientation = 0;
```

Override method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
    if(orientation != lastOrientation){
       orienChanged  = true;
       lastOrientation = orientation ;
    }

}
```

Check the variable `orienChanged`  in `onCreate()` for only initial time it will be false,otherwise it must be true.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize new configuration oncreate... and make newConfigOD valiable global.

```
 Configuration newConfigOD = getResources().getConfiguration();
```

Then override this method..

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(videoview.getVideoWidth()> videoview.getVideoHeight())  {
        if (newConfigOD.orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } 
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Try this... this should work as per your requirement. And remove this if condition from onCreate()

Comment: But I have to get video size(height and width)  not videoview size(height and width) and it takes few seconds to load video size(height and width) because it loads from server. Suppose i run my code, the progress bar will    show till it load video, then if video loaded complete, i will check the dimension of video , then if height is greater then width then it will work normally, but if width is greater than height then i will have to change screen orientation to landscape mode but in this case again onCreate method will call and again progress bar will show which has already shown first

Answer (score 0):

Auto set orientation according to video scale.

1. Implement addVideoListener()

   ```
    videoPlayer.addVideoListener(new VideoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int 
        unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onRenderedFirstFrame() {}
    });
   ```
2. According to height & width set conditions

   ```
    if(width>height){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    if(height>width){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
   ```
3. Your final objective would be like

   ```
   videoPlayer.addVideoListener(new VideoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int 
              unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) { 
            if(width>height){
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
            if(height>width){
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
       }
       @Override
       public void onRenderedFirstFrame() {}
    });
   ```